# Clarification on what the author meant (Learning Python 5th Edition)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def mysum(L):
    return 0 if not L else L[0] + mysum(L[1:])

def mysum(L):
   return L[0] if len(L) == 1 else L[0] + mysum(L[1:])

def mysum(L):
    first, *rest = L
    return first if not rest else first + mysum(rest)
```

- The latter two also work on a single string argument *e.g* `mysum('spam')` because strings are sequences of one-character strings.
- The third variant works on arbitrary iterables, including open input files `mysum(open(name))`, but the others do not because they use index.
- The function header `def mysum(first *rest)`, although similar to the third variant, because it expects individual arguments not a single iterable.

The author seems to be implying that the variant with `(first, *rest)` as the input arguments wouldn't work with files but after experimenting with it, I found that it does work.

```
# Code I tried:
def mysum(first, *rest): 
    return first if not rest else first + mysum(*rest)
```

`mysum(*open("script1.py"))` works fine.

I think `mysum(open("script1.py"))` won't work because that what python would then see is `first = open("script1.py` and `rest = []` which means it's gonna give me the `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='script1.py' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>` because not `[]` is true.

Comment: Questions on SO must be self-contained, not reliant on external links. And code must be in the form of copyable text, not images. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah nearly committed a rookie mistake haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author wants a function that takes an iterable (e.g. a list, tuple, etc) as input and returns the sum, e.g. like this:

```
mysum(open("script1.py"))
```

When you write

```
mysum(*open("script1.py"))
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```
f = open("script1.py").readlines()
mysum(f[0], f[1], ..., f[n])
```

Note that here your code does not take an interable as input, instead it takes several separate arguments *which is not what the author wanted*.

Comment: Oh thanks for the explanation! I understand better now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using a tuple to explain what happens. The `*sequence` syntax is used for unpacking.

```
numbers = (1, 2, 3)

mysum(*numbers)   # this happens: mysum(1, 2, 3)
```

is equivalent to `mysum(1, 2, 3)`. The members are taken from the iterable and fed into the function as arguments. Using `*open('path/to/file')` causes the file to be opened and its contents passed into `mysum(L)` as arguments. This is equivalent to `mysum(open('path/to/file').read())`